# Duplicate panel items after upgrade to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, indicator, panel, duplicate

[image: dupes]

Hi folks. I just upgraded from Xubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 and seem to have loads of dupes in my panel icons. Including 2 copies of redshift twice. Is this because I had indicator plugin and the upgrade has added the seemingly identical status tray plugin? Which should I keep, the latter?

Similarly is Notification Plugin and Status Notifier Plugin the same stuff twice?

Thanks!

Edit: OK status notifier is the dupe of status tray. Manually hid items from status notifier, seems to work. But since I'd hidden everything, I figured I could just remove status notifier plugin. Wrong. Causes all dupes to return. Add SNP back, no settings option now, so can't hide things. Will reboot & see if that helps. Edit2: fixed. Except for redshift which is still there twice but I think that's on them. Edit3: [it is](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/818).

Comment: Will be an upgrade switch, but it could be solved by removing the duplicate items. Or is that not possible? "Which should I keep"? That's your choice.

Comment: Same issue for me after upgrading to Xubuntu 22.04 last week. No, you cannot remove the duplicate panel items. Yes, the status notifier is duplicating the items. On inspection, there is only one Linux process running represented by the 2 panel icons. My duplicated icons are Megasync, Slack, and Blueman.  Reboot does not change the situation.

Comment: I also upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and am seeing this behavior now. Going into Status Notifier Plugin and hiding everything seems to work.

Comment: How are you accessing this "Panel Preferences" menu? I'm on 22.04 and I cannot for the life of me find a dialog that looks remotely like what you have here. Nothing happens when I right-click the panel, and when I go into "Settings" in the menu, it just pulls up my WiFi settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by reading [this XFCE Forum discussion](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=15217), where it notes that there is a new item named "Status Tray Plugin", which replaces one or more older plugins. I had both old and new enabled, leading to duplication.

I found the option to remove the old one by right clicking on the panel -> Panel -> Panel Preferences -> Items tab.

This started when upgrading Xubuntu 20.04 to Xubuntu 22.04, so I assume the upgrade neglected to remove the older plugin when adding the newer plugin.

Comment: I presume the older plugin is "Status Notifier Plugin". Oddly enough, unlike you and foobrew & Richard Elkins, this is no longer a problem for me on 22.04...!

Comment: Is there any way to access these "Panel Preferences" in 22.04? I am on 22.04 and when I right click the panel it does nothing. I have searched at great length and cannot find any way in 22.04 to access the settings you describe here.

Comment: Right click (top) bar (panel), on the menu that pops up: Panel > Panel Preferences. Or in terminal: `xfce4-panel -p`.